# Excel VBA - How can you find and replace single quotes on a 30k character string?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a find and replace in excel but excel is not finding anything and i think it is due to the amount of characters as there are some that have around 30,000 and for example find Don't and replace with Dont.

I want to insert this data into SQL and this is why i am trying to remove all the single quotes, there are many Q and A's on find and replace but i cant find anything that works for the amount of characters my data has.

I am terrible at VBA and so i don't really have any code to share except the below which doesn't work.

```
Selection.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: I think using `find and replace` can replace `'` to empty string no matter how many character. 30000 characrter in a cell or in one worksheet?

Comment: `Selection.Replace` If all the text is in one cell then ensure the correct cell is selected. Or simply use the correct cell address. For example `Range("A1").Replace`. If the text is spread out in multiple cells then use `Cells.Replace`

Comment: Maybe your unspecified `LookIn:` parameter default is incorrect.  It will default to the last used.

Comment: So I have pasted the text into cell A1 which has a length of 24256 the last word being Lloyd's and im trying to replace this with Lloyds if i do ctrl f or use the code Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Replace _
  What:="'", Replacement:="TEXT_CHANGED", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True Nothing happens. If i paste it into notepad it finds the single quote.. Excel wont even find Lloyd

Comment: I have just tried this and it still does not work, if i delete the majority of my text down to 5000 characters it works, should i be doing a loop to split the text into chunks and then run a find and replace as there seems to be a limitation?

Comment: Second example on this [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#examples) works. with `Find("'", LookIn:=xlValues)` and `Replace(c.Value, "'", "")` ..

Comment: @Naresh thank you so much - I used ```Sub FindString()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:a10")
        Set c = .Find("'", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                c.Value = Replace(c.Value, "'", "quotechanged")
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
    End With

End Sub
this works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it seems instead of Range.Replace, Replace function works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Naresh who answered this.

```
Sub FindString()
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:a10")
    Set c = .Find("'", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Value = Replace(c.Value, "'", "quotechanged")
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With
End Sub
```